# read unobtrusive data using jQuery

Tags: jquery, unobtrusive

I do not find any example how to read unobtrusive data using jQuery. For example below

```
<a id="deleteFile" href="" data="123">Delete file</a>
```

I would like to read `data` attribute from a element. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to just get the element attribute

```
$('#deleteFile').attr('data');
```

If your using a newish jquery library version (higher than 1.6 i belive) you can also use HTML5 data attributes with jQuery's `data()`. Change your anchor link to something like

```
<a id="deleteFile" href="" data-fileid="123">Delete file</a>
```

then you can use

```
$('#deleteFile').data('fileid');
```

However do NOT use them interchangeably, use one method only otherwise you may incur issues later on as jQuerys `data()` will only READ the data attributes then store them in an internal cache. If you change anything via `data()`, it will not be changed in the actual tag attribute meaning `data()` and `attr()` will return different results thereafter

Answer (score 3):

You should be using `data-*` where `*` is a key you would like to use:

```
<a id="deleteFile" href="" data-file-id="123">Delete file</a>
```

then you can read with:

```
$('#deleteFile').data('fileId');
```

Youll notice the property was converted from `file-id` to `fileId` this happens automatically to conform with the spec. It should also be noted that jquery will attempt to conver a value to its javascript native type. Meaning the value of that access will be a javascript `Number` as opposed to s string. This can have implications if you have a leading `0` and becuase `01` would be converted to `1`. If you explicitly need the value as a string then use `attr`:

```
$('#deleteFile').attr('data-file-id');
```

You should also note that when using `attr` you give the full attribute name as-is instead of just the data property name in camelCase.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to define data attributes like this:

```
<a id="deleteFile" href="" data-id="123">Delete file</a>
```

Then you can read it:

```
var id = $('#deleteFile').data('id');
```

This is not really good idea to use `attr` for such situations.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with your coding then you may try this

```
var a = $("#deleteFile").attr("data");
```

Heres a demo http://jsfiddle.net/Ht7Eg/3/